# Kirchhoff's voltage law in a two-port network

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, basic, kirchhoffs-laws

In a tutorial about h parameters of a two port network, I find the below snippet in the image unable to grasp.

According to KVL, the total voltage in a loop is the algebraic sum of the individual voltages. But why in this tutorial (equation 1 in below image) it's given like that? It should be something like V1 = h11 I1 + V2 according to KVL. What does this h12 V2 mean?

The whole tutorial is [here](https://www.electrical4u.com/hybrid-parameters-or-h-parameters/).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> the total voltage in a loop is the algebraic sum of the individual voltages.

This is KVL, not KCL.

> It should be something like V1 = h11 I1 + V2 according to KCL.

The voltage across the resistor is \$h_{11}I_1\$ and the voltage across the controlled voltage source is \$h_{12}V_2\$.

Therefore the KVL equation for this subcircuit is

$$V_1 = h_{11}I_1 + h_{12}V_2$$

as shown in the quoted text.

> What is this h12 V2 mean?

\$h_{12}V_2\$ is the voltage across the VCVS shown in the diagram.

\$h_{12}\$ is the gain of the VCVS.

\$V_2\$ is the voltage across the other port of the 2-port. This is shown in the very next diagram in the linked tutorial.

> [image]

Comment: I made some mistakes in my actual question. Now I have edited the question. Can you tell me how the equation 1 represents the circuit diagram? How did the author conclude that KVL applicable there?

Comment: Why do you think KVL wouldn't be applicable? So long as we don't violate the lumped circuit approximation, KVL can be applied to any path we like around a network.

Answer (score 0):

The two port parameters are given by the equation:
\begin{gather}
\begin{bmatrix}
V_1\\
I_2
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
h_{11} & h_{12}\\
h_{21} & h_{22}
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
I_1\\
V_2
\end{bmatrix} \end{gather}

It is from here that we get the two equations mentioned in the question.
$$
V_1 = h_{11} I_1 + h_{12}V_2
$$
$$
I_2 = h_{21} I_1 + h_{22}V_2
$$
Then an equivalent circuit is drawn for the first equation. If we consider the first equation as a KVL analysis of a network, then the network has to be the one given in the question.

*It should be something like V1 = h11 I1 + V2 according to KVL. What is this h12 V2 mean?*

\$h_{12} V_2\$ comes from the matrix equation. To represent it in the diagram, a VCVS is used with voltage as \$h_{12}V_2\$. The equations are not written by KVL analysis of a network, rather a network has been drawn which, when analysed using KVL, will give you the equations.